# HTML/CSS table-layout fixed but want one td to be a smaller width

Tags: html, css, html-table, tablelayout

I have a table with 4 columns. I want the first one to be a fixed 5% and the next 3 to be a fixed 20%. So in order to make sure the last 3 are always the same width I am using `table-layout:fixed`. However, this is causing the first td to be the same width as the last 3 columns.

Here's my HTML:

```
<tr>
<td class="groupsOptionsCheckboxCell"><input type="checkbox"/></td>
<td>{{COMPONENT_NAME}}</td>
<td>{{CO}}</td>
<td>{{PANEL_OPTIONS}}</td>
</tr>
```

And my CSS:

```
.creatorOptionsTable {border-collapse: collapse; width: 80%; table-layout: fixed;}
.creatorOptionsTable tr {border-bottom: 1px solid black;}
.creatorOptionsTable td {padding: 5px 3%; width: 20%; border-left: 1px solid black;    word-wrap: break-word}
 .creatorOptionsTable td.groupsOptionsCheckboxCell, .creatorOptionsTable th.groupsOptionsCheckboxCell {width: 5% !important;  text-align: center; border-left: none;}
```

Note, I'm aware that I haven't included the `<table>` tag in this. But it is there.

Seems like this should be easy, but won't work.

---

Well here is my entire code:

```
 <table id="creatorOptionsAddTable" class="creatorOptionsTable">
<tr class="firstRow">
    <th clas="groupsOptionsCheckboxCell"></th>
    <th>Component</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Panel</th>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td class="groupsOptionsCheckboxCell"><input type="checkbox"/></td>
<td>{{COMPONENT_NAME}}</td>
<td>{{COMPONET_DESCRIPTION}}</td>
<td>{{PANEL_OPTIONS}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: why don't you do this in plain html, if this css is giving problem. if would be a very helpful it you can creat this scenario in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QWsZT/)

Comment: Here is my scenario is jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/QWsZT/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are misunderstanding what this means:

```
.creatorOptionsTable { width: 80%; }
```

This sets the table element to 80% of the parent element.  So if your parent is 1000px -- this would be telling the browser, "make this table 800px".  THEN, it orders the width of the columns.

Second, if you are going to set the width of each column, it must equal 100%.  The browser can't account for all columns totalling less the 100%.  It would be like saying: there are 8 slices of pizza: Joe ate 1, John ate 2, Sam ate 2, Steve ate 2 -- we ate the whole pizza -- FALSE.

Understanding that, if you want one column to be 1/4th of the other three columns.  Should be about 8%, and 30%, 31%, 31% (or just do 10, 30, 30, 30).  Or you can just set the width of the 3 the same, and the narrow will fill the remaining space.

Answer (score 1):

That should work just fine.  That's not all your HTML though right?  Make sure you declare the table class as well.  I have edited the code to take your entire HTML sample into account.  The problem was that you had no CSS rules for your ths declared, so they were impacting the width of your tds.  Let me know if this still doesn't work, although it works fine in jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/QWsZT/2/).

HTML:

```
<table id="creatorOptionsAddTable" class="creatorOptionsTable">
<tr class="firstRow">
    <th class="groupsOptionsCheckboxCell"></th>
    <th>Component</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Panel</th>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td class="groupsOptionsCheckboxCell"><input type="checkbox"/></td>
<td>{{COMPONENT_NAME}}</td>
<td>{{COMPONET_DESCRIPTION}}</td>
<td>{{PANEL_OPTIONS}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.creatorOptionsTable {border-collapse: collapse; width: 80%; table-layout: fixed;}
.creatorOptionsTable tr {border-top: 1px solid black;}
.creatorOptionsTable tr.firstRow {border-top: none;}
.creatorOptionsTable td {padding: 5px 3%; width: 20%; border-left: 1px solid black; word-wrap: break-word}
.creatorOptionsTable td.groupsOptionsCheckboxCell, .creatorOptionsTable th.groupsOptionsCheckboxCell {width: 5% !important;  text-align: center; border-left: none;}
.creatorOptionsTable th {padding: 5px 3%; width: 20%; border-left: 1px solid black; word-wrap: break-word}
.creatorOptionsTable th.groupsOptionsCheckboxCell, .creatorOptionsTable th.groupsOptionsCheckboxCell {width: 5% !important;  text-align: center; border-left: none;}
```

Comment: How do you post code in comments? I will include my whole thing.

Comment: Check the updated code, it should work.  I have included the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Ah! I found it. I had this here before I decided to use table-layout: fixed:

```
.creatorOptionsTable {width: 80%;}
```

Take that out, and it's fixed. Thanks for help anyway guys!

Comment: Nope, that actually didn't fix it either. Now with that gone, the 3 columns on the right are different lengths.

Answer (score 1):

ahhh so you are doing a silly mistake check in your th tag what you have written

```
<th clas="groupsOptionsCheckboxCell"></th>
```

do you think its right.

Answer (score 0):

Set the general width of `td` to like `30px` and fix it with `max-width`, then set the width of the other 3 to 20% with recurring `+td` (`td+td` means second `td` and on, `td+td+td` means third `td` and on, etc...)

```
/*Set first (general) width fixed*/
.creatorOptionsTable td {
    width: 30px;
    max-width: 30px;
}
/*Set recurring cells' width 20%*/
.creatorOptionsTable td+td {
    width: 20%;
}
```

Also put the table inside a `div` with a width of 80% and set the width of the table to `100%`:

```
div.container {
    max-width: 80%;
}
.creatorOptionsTable {
    width: 100%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```